# How do I split a string by the URLs inside the string?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I would like to split a string into an array of strings based on the URLs inside the string.

For example, if my string is

"Hello this is a string https://www.google.com more stuff www.address.co end of sentence."

Then I would like to get

["Hello this is a string ", "https://www.google.com", " more stuff ", "www.address.co", " end of sentence."]

```
function split(s) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    "(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}/)"
  )
  return s.split(pattern)
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working for me.  I am getting this:

["Hello this is a string ", "https://www.google.com more ", "stuff www.address.co end of sentence."]

Comment: When you split like this, wrap the whole pattern with capturing group, and make all other groups non-capturing. Besides, inside a constructor notation, backslashes should be doubled. Or. use a regex literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to double escape your regexp since you are passing it as a string to be parsed.

Then you also need to make the final `/` optional (*and also add it to the first case*)

so

```js
function split(s) {
  const pattern = new RegExp( "(https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}/?|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}/?)" );
  return s.split(pattern)
}

console.log( split('Hello this is a string https://www.google.com more stuff www.address.co end of sentence.') );
```

---

if you were using a regular expression literal it would almost work directly (*you would need to escape the `/`*)

```js
function split(s) {
  const pattern = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}\/?|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}\/?)/;
  return s.split(pattern)
}

console.log( split('Hello this is a string https://www.google.com more stuff www.address.co end of sentence.') );
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.  I noticed that if I end the address with a punctuation mark, then the mark will get included in the address.  Is there any way to exclude it? "Hello this is a string https://www.google.com, more stuff www.address.co."

Comment: @OliverS would you be sure it is not part of the url ? ie. "**www.domain.ext/?query=ending-in-dot.**" is a valid url.

Comment: For now, I would like to assume that we are not submitting URLs with ending punctuation, but okay to have URLs with punctuation if it is followed up by another non punctuation non space character, like "www.google.com/blah.2stuff?here" is an okay url, but I would like "www.google.com/." to just return "www.google.com/" and the period to be kept separate.  Do you have suggestions for how to do this?